# SQL query select with multiple dynamic conditions

Tags: php, sql

I want to perform a SELECT query with conditions which are filled dynamically.

```
if($_POST['a']=='true'){
    $a = 'a,';
    $a_where = 'a >0';
}
if($_POST['b']=='true'){
    $b = 'b,';
    $b_where = 'b >0';
}
if($_POST['c']=='true'){
    $c = 'c,';
    $c_where = 'c >0';
}
```

Than i was tring to make WHERE

```
$where = 'WHERE '.$a_where.' OR '.$b_where.' OR '.$c_where;
```

And query

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT id,'.$a.$b.$c.'date FROM t_name '.$where.' ORDER BY date DESC');
```

Problem is if `b` or `a` is not POST than i have error in query. Actualy only WHERE clause is problem here.

Comment: When building out WHERE statements dynamically always include WHERE 1=1, then on fields you want to add dynamically you just add the "AND field logic"  "OR field logic" for each field, and your where clause will work properly

Comment: You can collect these in an array and use implode(",",...) or implode("OR",...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building the as separate variables, it's easier to collect them as arrays, do this for both the column names and the parts of the where clause and then use `implode()` to build the full SQL...

```
$columns = [ 'id', 'date' ];
$where = [];
if($_POST['a']=='true'){
    $columns[] = 'a';
    $where[] = 'a >0';
}
if($_POST['b']=='true'){
    $columns[] = 'b';
    $where[] = 'b >0';
}
if($_POST['c']=='true'){
    $columns[] = 'c';
    $where[] = 'c >0';
}

$sql = 'SELECT '.implode(",", $columns).'
          FROM t_name 
          WHERE '.implode(" or ", $where).' 
          ORDER BY date DESC';
```